# Using php variable in test.js file

Tags: javascript, php

I've changed my file extension of the javascript file to .php . Here is my code in **index.html**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.php"></script>
```

i've corrected header on top of the test.php using

```
  <?php
        header("Content-type: text/javascript");
$test=50; ?>
// my javascript

    var lineChartData = {
        labels : ["test1","test2","test3","test4","test4","test6","test7"],
        datasets : [
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                data : [<?PHP echo test; ?>,59,90,81,56,55,40]
            },
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
            }
        ]

    };
```

I cant pass a php varibale in the javascript  `data : [<?PHP echo test; ?>,59,90,81,56,55,40]`

Any help?

Comment: I would like to mention, that mixing PHP and JS in one file is very bad idea. You should output all neded varialbes by PHP and then use them in JS file. After some time it will get very difficult to manage JS file with PHP code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Heredoc

You need to print the text.

surround your javascript with the following:

```
echo <<<EOD

Javascript goes here

EOD;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your file has wrong syntax. It should be:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
?>
// my javascript
var lineChartData = {
    labels : ["test1","test2","test3","test4","test4","test6","test7"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
        }
    ]

};
```